# Rings and Semi-simple rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I'm failing to see which of the following are semi-simple rings, any help would be appreciated.

$\mathbb{C}[X]$, the group ring $\mathbb{Q[Z]}$ and 
$\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Q}\\
0 & \mathbb{Q}
\end{pmatrix}$

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know that semisimple rings are artinian?

Comment: and/or does semisimple mean "Jacobson radical zero" to you?

Comment: @Dune ah yes I do

Comment: @rschwieb semi simple to me means that that it is the direct sum of simple modules

Comment: @Richard OK thanks for the clarification! Some authors use the terms differently, but my preference is the way you're using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$\Bbb C[X]$ is a domain, and a domain is Artinian only if it's a field...

$\Bbb Q[\Bbb Z]$ is a group algebra over an infinite group, but a group algebra over a field is Artinian iff the group is finite...

The last ring $\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Q}\\
0 & \mathbb{Q}
\end{pmatrix}$ has a nonzero nilpotent ideal, hence its Jacobson radical is not zero. Find the nilpotent ideal. Alternatively, you can work to show it's not Artinian. You can, in fact, find a two-sided ideal such that the quotient is $\Bbb Z$. Can you see why this implies the ring isn't Artinian?

Comment: ah perfect thank you for the hints! @rschwieb

Comment: The last ring is also not artinian. Just replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by $n \mathbb{Z}$ for an infinitely descending sequence of left ideals.